# Eager loading a custom join with an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a system that allows users to invite other users to events:

```
class Event
  has_many :invites
end

class User
  has_many :invites
  has_many :invited, inverse_of: :inviter, foreign_key: :inviter_id, class_name: 'Invite'
end

class Invite
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :invited, -> (invite) { where(invites: { event_id: invite.event_id }) }, through: :user, class_name: 'Invite'
end
```

I'm generating a simple report that shows all the invites for an event. I'm trying to modify the report to also include some actions that can be done against the `invited` for the sample event:

```
<%- event.includes(:user).each do |invite| -%>
  <%= invite.user.name %>
  <%- invite.invited.each do |other| -%>
    <%= link_to invite_path(other), method: :destroy do %>
      ...
    <% end %>
  <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

This works fine but has a N+1 issue. Attempting to eager load the custom association gives:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The association scope 'invited' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading happens before the individual instances are created. This means that there is no instance being passed to the association scope. This will most likely result in broken or incorrect behavior. Joining, Preloading and eager loading of these associations is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Is there a way to do eager loading like this? Is it possible to give other hints to the `has_many` instead of using a instance variable?

Comment: I'm trying to grasp what you are trying to fetch. Invites from the same user to the same event?

Comment: @D-Side Yeah, trying to get other invites an each invited user made. The actual example is much more complex but I tried to simplify for this question as much as possible.

Comment: Well, you're fetching a collection of invites per invite. That WILL be a pain, since it requires a self join, which in turn requires aliasing one of the table instances involved. So, Arel usage appears to be a must.

Comment: Do you need to group invites by... uhm... invites? I mean, is a weirdly ordered list sufficient for your needs, or do you need it neatly grouped by the associated invite?

Comment: I don't see a definition of `invites` on `Invite`. Your example/naming of  associations is very confusing if correct at all. Since you didn't provide the schema, there is a lot of guesswork involded in order to undertstand what the schema is and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

See [Rails 5 how to form association between tables on multiple shared attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654098/rails-5-how-to-form-association-between-tables-on-multiple-shared-attributes).

You may need to define two different associations. One instance-specific and the other to use during joins.

Answer (score 0):

try just to use relation from event side. like:

```
class Invite
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: 'User'

  def invited
    event.invites.includes(...)
  end
end
```

Comment: base on OP `Invite.invited` query other `invites` that has the same `inviter`(user) and `event` with the invite , so i think your query `event.invites`  not enough. Could  you explain more details ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick in the view file

```
event.includes(:invite, :user).each do |invite|
  ...
```

Comment: For your block you named the attribute "invite" but it would return an object of the `event` type. Further, the event object does not have an association `invite` to eager load, it has `invites` and it does not have anything resembling `user`. Is this the snippet you meant to provide as an answer? Did you mean to leave this as a comment to another answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `event` is actually `event.invites`, try this:

```
<%- invites = event.invites -%>
<%- invites.includes(:user).each do |invite| -%>
  <%= invite.user.name %>
  <%- invites.select{|i| i.inviter == invite.user}.each do |other| -%>
    <%= link_to invite_path(other), method: :destroy do %>
      ...
    <% end %>
  <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

> Previous Solution
>
> ```
> <%- event.invites.includes(user: :invited).each do |invite| -%>
>  <%= invite.user.name %>
>  <%- invite.user.invited.select{|i| i.event_id == invite.event_id}.each do |other| -%>
>    <%= link_to invite_path(other), method: :destroy do %>
>      ...
>    <% end %>
>  <%- end -%>
> <%- end -%>
> ```